# 2005 Hyundai Santa Fe headlights only work on high beam

Tags: hyundai, headlight

The lights only work when the high beam switch is pulled back and the lights will not work normally. The fuse is good but replaced anyway and the steering column switch was replaced but no change.

Comment: Could both bulbs low beam be burned out?

Comment: When the high beam switch is pulled back and held, the lights work as normal. All lights appear normal.

Comment: I have read similar problems with everyone offering good advice but no one seems to have solved this yet.

Comment: Did you check the relays?

Comment: Next on the list as soon as it stops raining.